# R lists - deleting multiple entries to create a new list

Tags: r, list

I have the following:

```
Lst <- list('1'=c(323, 324), '2'=c(391, 392), '3'=c(923,924), '4'=c(301, 302))
```

and would like to get a list where the second number from which entry is gone, ie it would look like:

```
Lst_new <- list('1'=c(323), '2'=c(391), '3'=c(923), '4'=c(301))
```

I tried to accomplish that by creating two vectors, one which stores only the first number for each entry

```
vec<-c()
for (i in 1:length(Lst)){
temp<-paste(i)
vec<-c(vec, ind[[temp]][[1]])
}
```

and the other storing the id

```
vec_id<-c(1:length(vec))
```

and then putting them together, but I have a hard time figuring out string how to deal put in back together niceley.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply(Lst,"[[",1)
$`1`
[1] 323

$`2`
[1] 391

$`3`
[1] 923

$`4`
[1] 301
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the second element and there are more than two elements:

```
> lapply(Lst, "[", -2)
$`1`
[1] 323

$`2`
[1] 391

$`3`
[1] 923

$`4`
[1] 301
```

Comment: yes, this worked on the Lst example as well. However, here `load(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30578197/Lst.RData"))` I have the real data both of class matrix, both of same structure BUT one works with the code, and the other does not (Error in FUN(X[[59L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds) and I am not sure why is that.

Comment: @user1185196: my answer works on both objects. @James answer gives an error with `Lst.2` because 16 list elements of `Lst.2` have a length of 0, and you can't select the first element of a zero-element vector.